# Tkinter show label after function called when label should di

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-label

Tkiner display the label after callback function. but i display label in the top.

```
def records():
    lbl = tk.Label(recordWindow, text="recording")
    lbl.grid()
    Audio1()
 
btn = tk.Button(recordWindow, text="click to record",command=records)
btn.grid()
```

in this Audio1 function call and display the label.
I need display the label and call back the function.

I Need to display the "recording" and run the audio1() function. but what happened is after running the audio1() function it display the "recording" label

Comment: Your goal is just not clear to me here. Please try to explain what you want, what it does, and the difference between these two. Try adding [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the issue entirely, but here is a shot at it.
I added row and column parameters to the grid() method, so that `lbl` isn't at the top. I'm not certain of what label you want the Audio1 function to display. Perhaps you want it to flash on and off the lbl.

```py
def Audio1():
    global lbl
    if lbl.winfo_ismapped():
        lbl.grid_forget()
    else:
        lbl.grid()
    root.after(1000, Audio1)  # assumes your window is named root

def records():
    global lbl
    lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Audio1()

lbl = tk.Label(recordWindow, text="recording") 
btn = tk.Button(recordWindow, text="click to record",command=records)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
```